# Drop doesn't work in fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I can drag the event but I can't drop it. I mean I can drag it around as long as I'm holding it. But when I release event it immediately returns to the position before the drag.
And so the event `eventDrop` has not ever been called.

I have all properties set to right values. Have checked them multiple times. All other functions like `resize` work fine.

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    monthNames: ['Январь', 'Ферваль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
    monthNamesShort: ['январь', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'май', 'июнь', 'июль', 'август', 'сентябрь', 'октябрь', 'ноябрь', 'декабрь'],
    dayNames: ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'], 
    dayNamesShort: ['ВС', 'ПН', 'ВТ', 'СР', 'ЧТ', 'ВТ', 'СБ'],
    buttonText: {
        prev:     '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;',
        next:     '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
        prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
        nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
        today:    'сегодня',
        month:    'месяц',
        week:     'неделя',
        day:      'день'
    },
    titleFormat: {
        month: 'MMMM yyyy',
        week: "d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d, MMMM, yyyy}",
        day: 'd, MMMM, yyyy, dddd'
    },
    columnFormat: {
        month: 'dddd',
        week: 'ddd, d.M',
        day: 'dddd d.M'
    },
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}',
        '': 'H(:mm)'
    },
    weekMode: 'liquid',
    header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month today prev,next'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    axisFormat: 'H:mm',
    defaultEventMinutes: 60,
    slotMinutes: 30,
    minTime: 8,
    maxTime: 20,
    firstDay: 1,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    disableDragging: false,
    disableResizing: false,
    select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            ...
        },
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            ...
        },
    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
        ...
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, you did it right, but it isn't working. How exactly should we be able to help you after such a statement? Especially since you have posted no code at all. If you believe it's a bug, file a bug report.

Comment: I've added my code. I din't do this at first because I thought that someone has already faced with this problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a know bug. I assume you are using the most recent version of jQuery; version 1.7+
If that's the case you need to update fullcalendar.js to the most recent build.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar.git
$ cd fullcalendar
$ make
$ cd build/fullcalendar
```

copy *.js and *.css files

Comment: I'm confused. There's no fullcalendar.js or fullcalendar.css files. And I'm not familiar to Java to build it from source. And it seems that version on developer's site is not the recent one. But nevertheless thank you for your answer! At least I do know that it's not me stupid.

Comment: Indeed I'm stupid. I've run *make* command and all is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right drop method?

`eventDrop` is for when you're moving an event that already exists on the calendar to another date. For that, your code works fine.

`drop` is for when you're taking a jQuery-UI draggable object and dropping it on the calendar. You do not have code to handle this. You need to set the `droppable` option to `true` and hook up to the `drop` method.

Try this, my changes are near the bottom

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Ферваль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['январь', 'февраль', 'март', 'апрель', 'май', 'июнь', 'июль', 'август', 'сентябрь', 'октябрь', 'ноябрь', 'декабрь'],
        dayNames: ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'], 
        dayNamesShort: ['ВС', 'ПН', 'ВТ', 'СР', 'ЧТ', 'ВТ', 'СБ'],
        buttonText: {
            prev:     '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;',
            next:     '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
            prevYear: '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;',
            nextYear: '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
            today:    'сегодня',
            month:    'месяц',
            week:     'неделя',
            day:      'день'
        },
        titleFormat: {
            month: 'MMMM yyyy',
            week: "d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d, MMMM, yyyy}",
            day: 'd, MMMM, yyyy, dddd'
        },
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'dddd',
            week: 'ddd, d.M',
            day: 'dddd d.M'
        },
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'H:mm{ - H:mm}',
            '': 'H(:mm)'
        },
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        header: {
            left:   'title',
            center: '',
            right:  'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month today prev,next'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        axisFormat: 'H:mm',
        defaultEventMinutes: 60,
        slotMinutes: 30,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 20,
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        disableDragging: false,
        disableResizing: false,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {

            },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            },
        eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

        },
        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
           alert('Moving an event'); 
        },

        droppable: true,
        drop: function(date, allDay) {
           alert('Dropping an external event');

           // The rest of this method is taken from external-dragging.html from the demo files

           // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object  
             var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

           // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object 
             var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

           // assign it the date that was reported
             copiedEventObject.start = date;
           copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

             // render the event on the calendar
             // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

             // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
             if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
             // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
               $(this).remove();
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, I already know that. And I am using _eventDrop_ for moving an existing event. But my code doesn't work. Moreover _eventDrop_ is never called when I'm releasing an event after I've moved it. I don't use external objects at all.

Comment: @witzawitz, would it be possible for you to post a live copy? Your code works fine for me when moving an existing item.

Comment: I've created test user for you. Please follow the link http://opusmeeting.witzawitz.ru/calendar/. Site is in Russian, sorry for that. Login: test, password: testuser.

Comment: any fix for this? Fullcalendar is up to date and I still cannot drop my events

Comment: @witzawitz http://opusmeeting.witzawitz.ru/calendar <-- this link no longer works. :( (I opened it in Chrome)